# Get Column Name As Key and Column Data As Value Using Linq C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have to display data from a table with column names and I am using LINQ query to get data from the database. I have to select only one row from the table.

**Data Row**

```
 | Column 1 | | Column 2 |  | Column 3 |
 ------------ ------------  ------------
 | value1   | |  value 2 |  | value 3  |
```

**Data will display in this form.**

```
| Column Name |  | Value   |

| Column 1    |  | value 1 |

| Column 2    |  | value 2 |

| Column 3    |  | value 3 |
```

Is there any way to get data into the dictionary where column name will use as Key and Data as Value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to get data in my desired form using following code.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
   db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; // disable lazy loading if require.
   var dataFromDB= db.TestTable.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
   var props = dataFromDB.GetType().GetProperties(); // Get All properties of table class
   foreach (var column in props)
   {
      string columnName = column.Name;
      string columnValue = string.Empty;
      if(column.GetValue(dataFromDB) != null) // check obj has value for that particular property
      {
         columnValue = column.GetValue(dataFromDB).ToString();
      }
      dictionaryData .Add(columnName,columnValue); // Add Column Name as key and Column Data As Value
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. If I understand correctly, your table looks like:

```
| Column name |
---------------
| value1      |
| value2      |
```

And you would like to have two dictionary entries

```
Key = "Column name", Value = "value1"
Key = "Column name", Value = "value2"
```

In C# with dictionary you cannot have that! The "Key" must be unique.
Check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx
(scroll down to the Remarks section).

You could do some dirty workarounds like:

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>>
```

But this looks very dirty!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Actually, I have to get only one record from table therefor column name will not repeat and I can use it as Key.